# Modify Managed Navigation Default Page Settings in Onet

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I wanted to control the option of friendly urls option available in SharePoint 2013 through the web-templates. Can anybody help me with the exact property name required in the onet.xml?
I have seen this property available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.navigation.webnavigationsettings.createfriendlyurlsfornewpages.aspx

-Sharath

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to figure out the details how to achieve this using onet.xml. 
During my debugging this is what I cud see in ILSPY

[image: Navigation Settings for 2013]

So, the only way I could change the navigation to standard portal navigation was to update the navigation settings in a feature event receiver.